# Openlayers 7.1.0: Using a Style Function with WebGLPointsLayer/VectorSource

Tags: openlayers

I have a simple Openlayers 7.1.0 app (Node.JS) which processes 30K+ records & plots them on a map using a WebGLPointsLayer & a VectorSource. With a static style object each point is rendered but I'd like to style each point based on Features. I tried a Style Function but the style **function**, not the compiled style, is passed to parseLiteralStyle() which fails with *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'size')*.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Repo: https://github.com/Tomcariello/ol-plot_direction_and_magnitude-WebGL

```
const map = new Map({
  layers: [new Tile({source: new OSM()}),
    new WebGLPointsLayer({
      source: new VectorSource({ features: featuresArr,}),

      // THIS STATIC STYLE OBJECT WORKS AS EXPECTED
      style: {
        symbol: {
          symbolType: "triangle",
          size: 8,
          color: "blue",
          rotateWithView: true,
        }
      }

      // A STYLE FUNCTION FAILS TO RENDER
      // Result: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'size')
      // style (feature, resolution) {
      //   return { 
      //     symbol: {
      //       symbolType: "triangle",
      //       size: 8,
      //       color: "blue",
      //     }
      //   }
      // }
    }),
  ],
  target: "map",
  view: new View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2,
  }),
});
```

Comment: Style functions are not supported for WebGL points because the style object can access properties of the features using an expression such as `['get', 'speed']` for example https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-forked-ptw09b?file=/main.js

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again to @Mike above for providing the solution which has been pushed to the [repo](https://github.com/Tomcariello/ol-plot_direction_and_magnitude-WebGL).

"Style functions are not supported for WebGL points because the style object can access properties of the features using [a Style] Expression".

Click here to learn more about Openlayers [Style Expressions](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_style_expressions.html)

And here is the working style expression for my issue.

```
style: {
    symbol: {
      symbolType: "triangle",
      size: [
        "array",
        ["*", ["get", "speed"], 0.3], // speed * 0.3 --> width (triangle base)
        ["*", ["get", "speed"], 0.8], // speed * 0.8 --> height (triangle peak)
      ],
      color: [
        "case",
        [">", ["get", "speed"], 40], // if speed over 40 --> red
        "red",
        [">", ["get", "speed"], 20], // if speed over 20 --> blue
        "blue",
        "green", // if speed <= 20 --> green
      ],
      rotation: ["*", ["get", "deg"], Math.PI / 180],
      rotateWithView: true,
    },
  },
}),
```